# No output from cmd command calling powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, formatting, cpu-usage

Perhaps this is a crude question, but I have a code in powershell that returns CPU usage for every logical CPU core:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor") | foreach-object { write-host "$($_.Name): $($_.PercentProcessorTime)" };
```

in powershell, this code returns the following:

```
0: 0
1: 6
10: 6
11: 0
2: 0
3: 19
4: 0
5: 12
6: 0
7: 0
8: 0
9: 12
_Total: 4
```

Now I have been trying to get the same output running this command in command prompt by formatting the command to avoid errors. This is what I have now:
In CMD:

```
Powershell.exe 'Get-WmiObject -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor"' ^| foreach-object { write-host "$($_.Name): $($_.PercentProcessorTime)" };
```

which returns:

```
 :
```

which is different than the powershell output. I am almost certain this is due to some kind of formatting issue, but what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read `PowerShell -Help` for `PowerShell.exe` valid arguments.

> ```
> -Command
> …
> If the value of Command is a string, Command must be the last parameter
> in the command , because any characters typed after the command are
> interpreted as the command arguments.
>
> To write a string that runs a Windows PowerShell command, use the format:
>     "& {<command>}"
> where the quotation marks indicate a string and the invoke operator (&)
> causes the command to be executed.
> ```

2. Note that *inner* double quotes are escaped as

```
powershell -nopro -command "& {(Get-WmiObject -Query \"select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor\") | foreach-object { write-host \"$($_.Name): $($_.PercentProcessorTime)\" };}"
```

or

```
powershell -nopro -command "& {(Get-WmiObject -Query """"select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor"""") | foreach-object { write-host """"$($_.Name): $($_.PercentProcessorTime)"""" };}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just escape the internal doublequotes:

```dos
"%__AppDir__%\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "(Get-WmiObject -Query \"Select Name,PercentProcessorTime From Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor\")|ForEach-Object{\"$($_.Name): $($_.PercentProcessorTime)\"}"
```

You'll note that I removed the `Write-Host` command, because it wasn't needed.